# Reading each line of a text file and compare it to user input

Tags: java

Hello I am writing a program to read a sequential text file using step-wise refinement and upon running the program, either 1) insert 2) modify or 3) delete the entry given by the user. Currently my issue is that I need to input a string that exists (if it doesn't exit) then compare it to the "output" (or modified) string to modify it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class master2{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 1.insertion into file 2.modify into file 3.delete in file");
    int choice=sc.nextInt();
    try
    {
        File newTextFile = new File("masterfile.txt");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("duplicateMaster", ".txt", newTextFile.getParentFile());
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        if(choice==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter String to insert");
            String str = sc.next();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("masterfile.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            Scanner fileSC = new Scanner(newTextFile);
            int count = 0;
            while(fileSC.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = fileSC.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Line " + count + " " );
                count++;
                if (line.compareTo(str)==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Data already exists!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            fw.append("\n" + str);
            System.out.println("Entry added!");
            fw.close();
            fileSC.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(choice==2){
            Path path = Paths.get("masterfile.txt");
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("Enter String you want to modify which is present in text file");
            String input = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter new modified string");
            String output = sc.next();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(newTextFile), charset));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));
            Scanner fileSC = new Scanner(newTextFile);
            int count = 0;
            while(fileSC.hasNextLine())
            {
                String line = fileSC.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Line " + count + " " );
                count++;
                if (line.contains(input))
                {
                    content = line.replace(input, output);
                    writer.write(content);
                }
            }
            newTextFile.delete();
            temp.renameTo(newTextFile);
            System.out.print("Modified");
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        }
        if(choice==3)
        {
            String delete = "foo";
            System.out.println("Enter string to delete");
            delete = sc.nextLine();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(newTextFile), charset));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp), charset));
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                line = line.replace(delete, "");
                writer.println(line);
                temp.renameTo(newTextFile);
                temp.delete();

            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did recently add the while loop for `hasNextLine()` so I realize that It is probably incorrect.

Comment: You're missing a lot of code here, as it's truncated at the end of the `if(choice==2)` block, and the code formatting can use a lot of work. You're IDE can do the formatting for you if you're using one.

Comment: I was just putting in snipplets because I didn't want to seem like I was asking for it to be done for me. I have updated to the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

I spot a couple of problems problems.

1) You need to create the FileWriter for your temp file, not masterfile.txt.

2) If the string from the scanner doesn't match the input from the user you still need to write it to the temporary file, infact you don't even need to do that comparison, let `String.replace()` do it for you

```
while(fileSC.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = fileSC.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Line " + count + " " );
  count++;
  line = line.replace(input, output);
  bufferedWriter.write(line);
}
```

3) You can't just `System.exit(0)` once you found a match. What about the rest of the file? Also, you should probably close the Scanner and FileWriter.

Comment: I've made changes base on your suggestion, but it does not actually change the file. Is the `renameTo` function the one i need to use for this?

Comment: You need to rename the file AFTER you've written all of the lines to it, not after each and every line.